# Propositional Logic simple example

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have started studying Propositional Logic in my Masters degree.
I have a been given a number of examples and while I am going through them I seem to understand them but when after that presented with some questions to do on my own I seem to no be able to implement the logic. For example lets say you tell me to convert "Tom will go to the cinema or the swimming pool"
I will convert this to  A -> (B or C) where A is Tom, B is cinema and C is swimming pool.
Am I getting this example right ?

Comment: The variables in propositional logic represent propositions (also called statements or sentences). Tom, the cinema, and the swimming pool are not statements.

Comment: Extending Andreas Blass' comment, "John will do jumping jacks." is a proposition.